# Tail recursion implementation

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

In tail recursion, nothing is left to do after making the recursive call. But can that call be mixed with conditional logic?

Like, is following implementation an example of tail recursion:

```
def fibonacci(n:Int):Int = {
  def go(count:Int, n1: Int, n2:Int): Int = {
    if(count == n){
      n1+n2
    }else{
      val x = n2
      val y = n1+n2
      go(count+1,x,y)
    }
  }
  if(n == 1){
    0
  }else{
    if(n == 2){
      return 1
    }else{
      go(3,0,1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add a @annotation.tailrec tag before the method declaration, and the compiler will tell you. Especially if you put it in front of the inner method, which is, what might matter.

Comment: Btw: You get rid of the trailing if/else, by calling go (0, 0, 1), and returning n1 instead of n1+n2.

Comment: Hint: If it couldn't, every tail-recursion would be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a tail recursion, you could do whatever logic you want! It does not matter. What matters is that the last line of the method or to put it in other words, every place where your method returns should in fact either be a recursive call or the method should return completely out!

So basically, you treat your tail recursion as a while loop!

Have a look here for more information: [Understanding the Idea behind Tail Recursion in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043950/understanding-the-idea-behind-tail-recursion-in-scala)

Comment: I visited the link. So tail recursion more like a programming style.Can one implement it in a language like Java?

Comment: Yes, of course. Tail recursion is simply when the recursive call is also a tail call. Java has tail calls (*every* language has tail calls, a tail call is simply the "last call", and logically, there is always a last call) and Java has recursion (most languages nowadays have recursion, the last mainstream language that didn't, were early versions of FORTRAN back when it was still spelled FORTRAN and not Fortran). What Java *doesn't* have is *proper tail recursion*, i.e. tail recursion in O(1) space. So, yes, you can write tail-recursive code in any language that supports recursion, but you …

Comment: … only get the benefit in a language that has at least *proper tail-recursion* or the more general *proper tail calls* or *proper tail-recursion modulo `CONS`*. In Java, replacing a `while` loop with tail-recursion is likely to blow the stack, unless your problem size is really small. (And of course, using tail-recursion for an *infinite* or at least unbounded loop is right out in Java.)